# ODBC Data source name not found and no default driver specified issue when running app as a service

Tags: delphi, firedac

We have an app (server that will be deployed as service app) that connects to a database on a remote location to fetch configuration during startup. The Datasource name not found issue only happens when running the app a service but not when running as a console application.  The same codes are being called (in both modes) to construct connection string e.g. ConnectionString := Format('DriverID=ODBC;Datasource=%s;User_Name=%s;Password=%s;MARS_Connection=YES', [FODBCName, FUserName, FPassword]);

Another thing is the issue only occurs when we upgrade the app to 64bit. So when it was still 32bit we didn't have any issue running both as a console or service application.

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: When you press windows Start button and type 'ODBC' you should get: 'ODBC Data Sources (32-bit)' and 'ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)'. So, yes, there are separate definition of data sources for 32 and 64-bit applications. Also note that you should define the data source for the user account that runs the service (User DSN) or add a system-wide definition (System DSN).